# Figure to overlap text in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am making a `beamer` presentation. How can I force LaTeX to overlap text with a figure. I mean text is below the figure. Is it possible to try something like that with `beamer`?

Comment: Have you considered [adding a caption](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)? (Oh! and [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx))

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it's possible; use TikZ and put the image inside a `\node` to control position, opacity and other attributes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Needs two compilations.